# How to configure Django with Webpack/React using create-react-app on Ubuntu server

Tags: django, reactjs, nginx, webpack

I'm following this tutorial:

http://v1k45.com/blog/modern-django-part-1-setting-up-django-and-react/

The tutorial describes how to set up a Django/React app using webpack.

Everything works fine on my development machine but I have problems with the static files on a remote server (Ubuntu 16.04.4).

These are my questions:

1) Why is my development version looking for the static files in localhost?

2) If I use Nginx/Passenger to serve the production version, the static files are not loaded in the browser even though the links look correct. Why is this?

Edit: I think I've found the answer to setting up Passenger. Even though the wsgi.py loads the application, you need to tell Nginx where the static files are located. My working /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ponynote.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 178.62.85.245;

    passenger_python /var/www/ponynotetest/venv36/bin/python3.6;

    # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    root /var/www/ponynotetest/ponynote/ponynote;

    location /static/ {
       autoindex on;
       alias /var/www/ponynotetest/ponynote/assets/;
    }

    # Turn on Passenger
    passenger_enabled on;
}
```

3) Do I need to configure STATIC_ROOT for production and run collectstatic?

Many thanks for any help!

Here is more information and code:

In order to make sure I've not made any typos, I've cloned the source code, switched to the branch 'part-1' and followed all the instructions in the README.

I added 'xx.xx.xx.xx' to settings.py ALLOWED_HOSTS where xx.xx.xx.xx is my server's IP address.

I added "proxy": "http://localhost:8000" to frontend/package.json.

1) Development version

I'm running the development server with:

./manage.py runserver xx.xx.xx.xx:8000

I have also run 'npm run build' before starting the webpack server with 'npm run start' in the frontend folder.

The problem: when I navigate in a browser to xx.xx.xx.xx:8000, I see a blank page. This is the HTML:

```
<html><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Ponynote</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
    </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js"></script>
  </body></html>
```

It looks to me as though the page is trying to find bundle.js on localhost - I assume it should be looking on a relative path on the server. I guess this is why the code works if I run it on my local machine but not the server.

I can't find what in Django or Webpack specifies the location as localhost. Am I missing a setting or is this just not possible for some reason?

2) Nginx/Passenger

I've installed Nginx and Passenger according to the instructions:

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/python/digital_ocean/nginx/oss/xenial/deploy_app.html#edit-nginx-configuration-file

At xx.xx.xx.xx, the browser is showing what looks like the correct html but the files are not being loaded. See below the html served up by Nginx. Note that the static links show the correct relative URL, exactly the same as when running the Django server in production mode except not on port 8000, but the files themselves are not being loaded.

/var/log/nginx/error.log doesn't show any errors.

```
<html><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Ponynote</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
    </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bundles/js/main.a416835a.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="/static/bundles/css/main.c17080f1.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </body></html>
```

3) Django server running in production mode

If I run the Django server in production mode with the following:

./manage.py runserver --settings=ponynote.production_settings 178.62.85.245:8000

The page looks fine in the browser at xx.xx.xx.xx:8000 even though I have not run collectstatic. The tutorial says to run collectstatic but an error is shown if you try: 'You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path'. I don't know whether I need to set STATIC_ROOT in production_settings.py, or whether I don't need to run collectstatic?

Here are my setup files:

ponynote/templates/index.html

```
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Ponynote</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
    </div>
      {% render_bundle 'main' %}
  </body>
</html>
```

ponynote/settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '=e%s=1kdk1_+yur9cmpkw8r-z5gd(owqpxbyl+6^)*10-a3c4v'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['xx.xx.xx.xx']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'webpack_loader',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ponynote.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"), ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ponynote.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
            'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'bundles/',
            'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'webpack-stats.dev.json'),
        }
}
```

frontend/package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "6.25.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.0.3",
    "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "eslint": "4.4.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.35.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.1.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.6",
    "promise": "8.0.1",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^4.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "3.5.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.8.2",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.2.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "^0.2.0"
  }
}
```

frontend/config/webpack.config.dev.js

```
'use strict';

const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
const WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin');
const eslintFormatter = require('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter');
const ModuleScopePlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin');
const getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
const paths = require('./paths');
const BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');


// Webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
// In development, we always serve from the root. This makes config easier.
const publicPath = 'http://localhost:3000/';
// `publicUrl` is just like `publicPath`, but we will provide it to our app
// as %PUBLIC_URL% in `index.html` and `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in JavaScript.
// Omit trailing slash as %PUBLIC_PATH%/xyz looks better than %PUBLIC_PATH%xyz.
const publicUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/';
// Get environment variables to inject into our app.
const env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

// This is the development configuration.
// It is focused on developer experience and fast rebuilds.
// The production configuration is different and lives in a separate file.
module.exports = {
  // You may want 'eval' instead if you prefer to see the compiled output in DevTools.
  // See the discussion in https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/343.
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  // These are the "entry points" to our application.
  // This means they will be the "root" imports that are included in JS bundle.
  // The first two entry points enable "hot" CSS and auto-refreshes for JS.
  entry: [
    // We ship a few polyfills by default:
    require.resolve('./polyfills'),
    // Include an alternative client for WebpackDevServer. A client's job is to
    // connect to WebpackDevServer by a socket and get notified about changes.
    // When you save a file, the client will either apply hot updates (in case
    // of CSS changes), or refresh the page (in case of JS changes). When you
    // make a syntax error, this client will display a syntax error overlay.
    // Note: instead of the default WebpackDevServer client, we use a custom one
    // to bring better experience for Create React App users. You can replace
    // the line below with these two lines if you prefer the stock client:
    require.resolve('webpack-dev-server/client') + '?http://localhost:3000',
    require.resolve('webpack/hot/dev-server'),
    // require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
    // Finally, this is your app's code:
    paths.appIndexJs,
    // We include the app code last so that if there is a runtime error during
    // initialization, it doesn't blow up the WebpackDevServer client, and
    // changing JS code would still trigger a refresh.
  ],
  output: {
    // Next line is not used in dev but WebpackDevServer crashes without it:
    path: paths.appBuild,
    // Add /* filename */ comments to generated require()s in the output.
    pathinfo: true,
    // This does not produce a real file. It's just the virtual path that is
    // served by WebpackDevServer in development. This is the JS bundle
    // containing code from all our entry points, and the Webpack runtime.
    filename: 'static/js/bundle.js',
    // There are also additional JS chunk files if you use code splitting.
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
    // This is the URL that app is served from. We use "/" in development.
    publicPath: publicPath,
    // Point sourcemap entries to original disk location (format as URL on Windows)
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
      path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/'),
  },
  resolve: {
    // This allows you to set a fallback for where Webpack should look for modules.
    // We placed these paths second because we want `node_modules` to "win"
    // if there are any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/253
    modules: ['node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(
      // It is guaranteed to exist because we tweak it in `env.js`
      process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
    ),
    // These are the reasonable defaults supported by the Node ecosystem.
    // We also include JSX as a common component filename extension to support
    // some tools, although we do not recommend using it, see:
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/290
    // `web` extension prefixes have been added for better support
    // for React Native Web.
    extensions: ['.web.js', '.js', '.json', '.web.jsx', '.jsx'],
    alias: {

      // Support React Native Web
      // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
      'react-native': 'react-native-web',
    },
    plugins: [
      // Prevents users from importing files from outside of src/ (or node_modules/).
      // This often causes confusion because we only process files within src/ with babel.
      // To fix this, we prevent you from importing files out of src/ -- if you'd like to,
      // please link the files into your node_modules/ and let module-resolution kick in.
      // Make sure your source files are compiled, as they will not be processed in any way.
      new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson]),
    ],
  },
  module: {
    strictExportPresence: true,
    rules: [
      // TODO: Disable require.ensure as it's not a standard language feature.
      // We are waiting for https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2176.
      // { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },

      // First, run the linter.
      // It's important to do this before Babel processes the JS.
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        use: [
          {
            options: {
              formatter: eslintFormatter,
              eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),

            },
            loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
          },
        ],
        include: paths.appSrc,
      },
      {
        // "oneOf" will traverse all following loaders until one will
        // match the requirements. When no loader matches it will fall
        // back to the "file" loader at the end of the loader list.
        oneOf: [
          // "url" loader works like "file" loader except that it embeds assets
          // smaller than specified limit in bytes as data URLs to avoid requests.
          // A missing `test` is equivalent to a match.
          {
            test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
            loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
          // Process JS with Babel.
          {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            include: paths.appSrc,
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {

              // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
              // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
              // directory for faster rebuilds.
              cacheDirectory: true,
            },
          },
          // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
          // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
          // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
          // In production, we use a plugin to extract that CSS to a file, but
          // in development "style" loader enables hot editing of CSS.
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              require.resolve('style-loader'),
              {
                loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                options: {
                  importLoaders: 1,
                },
              },
              {
                loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                options: {
                  // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
                  // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
                  ident: 'postcss',
                  plugins: () => [
                    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                    autoprefixer({
                      browsers: [
                        '>1%',
                        'last 4 versions',
                        'Firefox ESR',
                        'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                      ],
                      flexbox: 'no-2009',
                    }),
                  ],
                },
              },
            ],
          },
          // "file" loader makes sure those assets get served by WebpackDevServer.
          // When you `import` an asset, you get its (virtual) filename.
          // In production, they would get copied to the `build` folder.
          // This loader doesn't use a "test" so it will catch all modules
          // that fall through the other loaders.
          {
            // Exclude `js` files to keep "css" loader working as it injects
            // it's runtime that would otherwise processed through "file" loader.
            // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
            // by webpacks internal loaders.
            exclude: [/\.js$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
            loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
            options: {
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
      // Make sure to add the new loader(s) before the "file" loader.
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    // Makes some environment variables available in index.html.
    // The public URL is available as %PUBLIC_URL% in index.html, e.g.:
    // <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    // In development, this will be an empty string.
    new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(env.raw),
    // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: paths.appHtml,
    }),
    // Add module names to factory functions so they appear in browser profiler.
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    // Makes some environment variables available to the JS code, for example:
    // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') { ... }. See `./env.js`.
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
    // This is necessary to emit hot updates (currently CSS only):
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    // Watcher doesn't work well if you mistype casing in a path so we use
    // a plugin that prints an error when you attempt to do this.
    // See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/240
    new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
    // If you require a missing module and then `npm install` it, you still have
    // to restart the development server for Webpack to discover it. This plugin
    // makes the discovery automatic so you don't have to restart.
    // See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/186
    new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules),
    // Moment.js is an extremely popular library that bundles large locale files
    // by default due to how Webpack interprets its code. This is a practical
    // solution that requires the user to opt into importing specific locales.
    // https://github.com/jmblog/how-to-optimize-momentjs-with-webpack
    // You can remove this if you don't use Moment.js:
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    new BundleTracker({path: paths.statsRoot, filename: 'webpack-stats.dev.json'}),
  ],
  // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
  // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
  node: {
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty',
  },
  // Turn off performance hints during development because we don't do any
  // splitting or minification in interest of speed. These warnings become
  // cumbersome.
  performance: {
    hints: false,
  },
};
```

Nginx/Passenger config:

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ponynote.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xx.xx.xx.xx;

    passenger_python /var/www/ponynote/venv36/bin/python3.6;

    # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    root /var/www/ponynote/ponynote/ponynote;

    # Turn on Passenger
    passenger_enabled on;
}
```

passenger_wsgi.py

```
import ponynote.wsgi
application = ponynote.wsgi.application
```

ponynote/wsgi.py

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ponynote.production_settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

ponynote/production_settings.py

```
from .settings import *
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets"),
]

WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
            'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'bundles/',
            'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'webpack-stats.prod.json'),
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the scripts don't load and you see the HTML of your homepage when you visit the script's URL in your browser, this means either your links are wrong or Nginx isn't serving up the files. (As there is no file at the URL, Nginx gives you the home page instead.) What I didn't realise at first is that although Nginx by default serves the Django app, it doesn't serve any static files that aren't in the 'public' folder, so doesn't serve the build output.

It also seems that create-react-app has changed since the tutorial I followed was written; you don't seem to need to do any webpack config now.

And finally you need to put the frontend build output somewhere the Django app will find it.

A newer tutorial led me to an approach which is working on the production server:
https://medium.com/alpha-coder/heres-a-dead-simple-react-django-setup-for-your-next-project-c0b0036663c6. I chose to keep frontend in its own folder, and I'm using Nginx/Passenger, so I made a couple of changes.

Here's how I set it up.

1) After setting up your Django project, create a React app in the project root folder with:

```
create-react-app frontend
```

2) Tell the Django project where to look for the React build output:
In djangoproject/settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
  {
    ...
    'DIRS': [
      os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
    ],
    ...
  }
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets/static'),
]
```

In djangoproject/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  # path('api/', include('mynewapp.urls')),
  re_path('.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
]
```

Add this at end of frontend/src/index.js to enable hot reloading:

```
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
}
```

3) Create a bash script in the project root to build the React pages and move them into an assets folder in project root:

```
buildapp.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
npm run build --prefix frontend
rm -rf ./assets
mv ./frontend/build ./assets
```

Run this script.

4) Tell nginx where to find the build output and the correct versio of Python (assuming you're using a virtual environment). I'm using Passenger to deploy the app so this code is in sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp.conf

```
passenger_python /var/www/myapp/venv36/bin/python3.6;

# Tell Nginx where your app's 'public' directory is
root /var/www/myapp/myapp/myapp;

# Tell Nginx the location of the build output files
location /static/ {
   autoindex on;
   root /var/www/myapp/myapp/assets;
}
```

I haven't run collectstatic and everything looks fine. I'm guessing you only need collectstatic for any other resources you may add in future.

Comment: I recently found that I do need to run collectstatic, and serve the collected files, in order to add a favicon. So I had to update the root and location paths to match.

Comment: I'm assuming this means the build script needs to be run after each change. How do you handle this for development? It seems a bit cumbersome to run a script each time you want to see a change.

Comment: It's been a while since I looked at this but IIRC in development, updates are handled for you by webpack. It's only when you need to do a production build that the files need to be copied over by your deployment script. Nginx is only running on my production server, not my development machine.